# nodemailer to send mail from portfolio site

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I have successfully created a Node.js server with Express and also installed nodemailer to send the data from the 'Contact Me' form from my front-end React app. I have uploaded this on Heroku.

I have a question though - since this endpoint is set up on this public domain, in theory, someone could inspect my source code, find the URL, and build a script out to make a ton of POST requests with random data to blow up my inbox.

Is there anything that can be done to stop this sort of behavior? Where would I even start to research into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Captcha could help you.

Comment: I think that will work yes. Didn't even think of Captcha and validating it on the server. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

CORS is what you're looking for. I recommend reading up a lot more on it since it will pay off greatly for your web development journey! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

The short answer is that you must set a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <yoursite>.com` header in CORS policy for your Node.js app ([install it from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)), which will turn down any requests made by a 3rd party actor who inspects the form destination address.

Comment: That's great. Thanks!

What about someone spamming cURL requests? Since that's not coming from a browser, how would you limit that?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't specifically block curl requests, but there are definitely ways to make those curl requests more difficult such as adding on requirements with additional headers. I would read into best practices, and then if it really concerns you, you can set up server-side spam detection in your node.js app as well.

Comment: I think the Captcha comment above is the solution. It looks like a lot of people validate those captchas on the server, a cURL request wouldn't be able to get around that afaik. So I think that will be my move forward.